# Reporting in .net winforms with end user designer

Tags: .net, reporting, designer

What are you guys using as reporting engine in .net, **with end user designing capabilities**?

I tried DevExpress XtraReports, but i am not able to successfully achieve consistent results. 
(for example, i try to display a detailreport of sold machines for a certain contact -> first  field works fine, other fields don't; no data in them. no matter what i do) That kind of inexplicable behavior is not really tolerated in an enterprise environment, so i'm curious what the other solutions are...

Update: It should be noted that the emphasis is on the end user designer part here. The customer should be able to modify the layout and fields (within limits) of the reports, without extensive IT knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

SQL server Reporting services for any dynamic reports generated or Report builder for adhoc reports.

Comment: Hmm yeah. But reporting services isn't really a technology i would recommend on teaching a customer... (He should be able to modify the layout and fields of the reports on his own without extensive IT knowledge)

Answer (score 1):

Data Dynamics Active Reports .Net... Fully integrated with Visual Studio,  can use either C# or VB.net,  and does not require a separate "reporting server",  so the dlls it produces are managed code assemblies that work within your managed code executable, and can be deployed as a dependant assembly with your executable or web application, across an application farm or web farm just like any other deployed application you write, with no additional license fees...

ALso incldues pdf, text xls and other automated report generators and viewers, and a end-user custom report generation tool. (so that end users can modify report layout, filtering and sorting options... )

http://www.datadynamics.com/Products/ProductFeatures.aspx?Product=ARNET3&Topic=End-User%20Report%20Designer

Comment: That's the kind of engine i'm talking about :) Will try that one out.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [Windward Reports](http://www.windwardstudios.com/). With Windward you design the reports in Microsoft Word, Excel, or PowerPoint - so no learning curve for your end users. (Disclaimier - I'm the CTO at Windward.)

As to your issue of not getting data back in some fields, that is more likely an issue with the selects you have crafted - I have not heard of any reporting system dropping data and DevExpress in particular writes solid code.